# Making Blogger post and page background transparent

Tags: html, css, background, blogger

I need to get the area outlined in red in the image below completely transparent. I'm new to this HTML stuff, but I've tried searching for transparency and opacity in the HTML editing section and I don't seem to be able to find the correct bit to edit.
If there's a simple CSS code someone could provide me with that would be even better.

I'm using the Picture Window theme on Blogger.

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS I would use is `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` (red,green,blue,alpha)

for alpha, 0 is transparent, 1 is solid, so 0.5 would be halfway transparent

If you are unsure where to put this css, you'll need to identify the div; you can use developer tools in most popular browsers to find the ID or Class of the div; right click on it and choose "Inspect" or "Inspect element" or similar.

**EDIT:**
The div you need to alter is `<div class="content-outer">....</div>`
add the style background:none; to remove the existing background.

```
<div class='content-outer' style="background:none;box-shadow:none;">
    <div class='content-cap-top cap-top'>
    <div class='cap-left'/>
    <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>
```

see [here](http://sourceofemahol.blogspot.com.au/)

If you want to ensure the box-shadow (fuzzy outline) does not appear on older browsers, see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp for browser specific css. For example for older versions of chrome you would also add `-webkit-box-shadow:none;`

Comment: Thank you, but it all it seems to do is make the actual blogger bg transparent. I've searched through the HTML for similar codes and changed each of those numbers to 0, but it makes no difference...

Comment: @Leela I have edited my answer with more specifics, see if that helps any :)

Comment: Terrific, that worked! I'm sorry to nit-pick, but there seems to be a faint, fuzzy line around where the background used to be. Do you have any idea how to get rid of that? :$

Comment: that's a box-shadow; see addition to answer.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much!